# RFID PCB coil output power much lower than expected

Tags: coil, rfid

I'm working on a PCB for RFID reading and writing however after assembling the PCB I have noticed the output field strength of the RFID coil is much lower than I anticipated.[image]

[image]

I was trying to copy the same coil design as used on the common Arduino RFID breakout board so the coil is four turns with 1mm trace width and 20mm radius. I did this as I don't have a network analyser which is needed to measure coil properties as stated in this application note from NXP [AN11564](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN11564.pdf). The best I have is an LCR meter but this can only measure up to 100kHz.

So the capacitor and inductor values for the filtering and matching stages are the same as on the breakout board. However, my PCB does not match the performance of the breakout board. I only get around 1.4V pk-pk across the coil compared to around 7V pk-pk on the breakout board. The majority of the MFRC output voltage is dropping across C27 and C20 (around 10V peak drop) but I'm not sure why. Is there anyway I can try to adjust the matching circuit systematically or do I need a network analyser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your antenna is actually a coil of wire and, it's primary goal is to generate a magnetic field at the operating frequency of the chip. To maximize that magnetic field you need to match the inductance with the tuning capacitors: -

[image]

> *So the capacitor and inductor values for the filtering and matching
> stages are the same as on the breakout board. However, my PCB does not
> match the performance of the breakout board.*

Ask yourself this: what are the chances that your homespun coil has an inductance value that is very close to the one you are replacing? I'll answer: not very good.

> *Is there anyway I can try to adjust the matching circuit
> systematically*

Yes, you need to establish if C22, C23, C24 and C25 require increasing in value or decreasing in value so, try adding 10 pF across C23 and 10 pF across C25 and, if your coil voltage reduces then you are going in the wrong direction and you will need to remove C23 and C25 and see if that is taking you in the right direction.

If it is then you will probably need to swap C22 and C24 for 150 pF capacitors and keep iterating until you have a decent enough voltage across your coil.

If when adding the 10 pF capacitors across C23 and C25 the coil voltage increased then try adding 22 pF instead and keep on going until you are happy with your performance.

<sub>But, if the inductance of your home-spun coil is vastly different to the original you may never get decent performance.</sub>

Comment: UPDATE: I tried capacitances from 10pF up to 350pF and was still unable to reach an output voltage higher than 1.4V. You said if the inductance is very different I may never get decent performance, why is this? My testing seems to confirm it but can't we come up with a matching circuit for any inductance by changing C22,23,24,25? Also, I measured my coil and got around 1.8uH at 100kHz whereas the breakout board is 1.5uH at 100kHz. Can the variation really be that much different at 13.56MHz?

Comment: If your coil has higher inductance then you need to reduce capacitance (as per my instructions). 1.8 uH vs 1.5 uH requires a capacitance reduction of the same ratio as the inductance i.e. choose 150 pF capacitors for C22 and C24. However, if the series resistance of your home-spun coil is significantly higher than the series resistance of the original coil then it may never produce a comparable performance @SwissGnome

Answer (score 1):

Given frequency 13.56 MHz, and your coil being 1.8 uH, Python says resonant capacitance is
((1./(13.56e6*2*3.14159))**2)/1.8e-6 = 7.65e-11 = 77pF

Using the formula for resonant frequency:
f = 1 / (2 * pi * sqrt(L * C))

C22 and C23 should add up to something close to 154 pF, since they are in series with C24 and C25.

Blue, green and red traces. Three layers visible out of four.  Is there any chance there is a ground plane under your coil? That would kill any resonance.

Answer (score 1):

I found the actual albeit much simpler solution to this issue. As it turns out my initial capacitor values for the matching circuit would've actually worked ok with my coil.

**THE ACTUAL ISSUE**

Whilst assembling this board I was using a stereoscopic microscope the base of which is metal with a silicone mat over the top and I also did all my initial testing while the board was sitting on this base. The coil's magnetic field of course interacted with the base creating eddy currents which weaken the coil field. This is the received voltage with a single loop with the board on the microscope base:[image]

And off the base:[image]

Big difference! Stupid of me to not realise this sooner.